# Removing spaces between "words" in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'd like to set `$1024 \times 768$` without any space between the three items. Is this possible? If so, how?

E.g., what I get is:

> 1024 x 768

and what I want is:

> 1024x768

Comment: @Marc, I want it because it looks better that way IMO. Not sure why anyone would want the letter `x`... that looks pretty sloppy.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Math binary operators and relations automatically add appropriate spaces between the symbol and their operands. If you want to remove this space, you can turn the operator into a regular symbol by enclosing it in braces. For example

```
$1024 {\times} 768$
```

If you will be using this often you can also define a new command and say something like

```
\newcommand{\stimes}{{\times}}
$1024 \stimes 768$
```

where `\stimes` is a *symbol* version of the `\times` *operator*.

Comment: Good answer, I'd only add 'however, you really shouldn't be doing this!'

Comment: That's what I tried to say with "appropriate spaces" in the first sentence, but I probably was't explicit enough. :P

Comment: @Joseph, you don't have to use it in your documents. I write documents that look the best I can make them, not ones that follow "the rules". I deliberately left out extraneous explanations and context, but it's a deliberate choice and it looks way better in my context.

Answer (score 27):

These answers seem overly complicated to me. I personally just use `\!` between symbols as in:

```
$W \! \rightarrow \! \mu$
```

This brings the symbols closer together. You can also use multiple in a row

```
$W \! \! \! \rightarrow \! \mu$
```

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant solution, but I don't want the most elegant solution for math mode on SE

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps defining it as an ordinary math symbol might be better than just enclose it in braces and expect that would do it now and in the future. So, I would use `\mathord`:

```
$1024\mathord{\times}768$
```

Comment: As Knuth points out in the TeXbook, `\mathord` is strictly unnecessary in TeX, since braces do the same thing. Unless you're planning on not using TeX in the future, I don't see why you would not expect it to work in the future.

Comment: Generally, I prefer a clear command like `\mathord` over that effect of braces which a reader perhaps might not recognize. Though you're right, this effect should not be changed in the future since subformulas should remain ordinary symbols. I just don't rely on side effects.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that what you really want is a multiplication sign that works in text mode.  You can get this by writing $\times$ or, to answer your whole question
**1024$\times$768**.

By the way, nice question.  This is a good example of where it makes sense not to use normal math typography.

Comment: This is easily the best answer. Screwing around with spacing in math mode is totally unnecessary if all you need is a symbol in your text.