# Spacing around a character in math mode

Tags: spacing

I'd like to use a character that looks like $\sim$, but has spacing like $\neg$ (in particular, which doesn't leave a huge gap to its right).  I know I could do this by defining a symbol which expands to $\sim\hspace{-1pt}$, with 1pt replaced by some amount that looks about right to me, but is there a better way to do this (for instance, which doesn't rely on my guess about what spacing looks about right)?

Comment: I am not too sure about your question but you can try one of these: `$\sim\!a$` or `$\sim\mkern-4.5mu a$`.

Comment: But why -4.5mu rather than, say -4mu?  Or -4.2mu?  (Indeed, -4.5mu seems to be running slightly into other characters.)

Comment: That was my guess to get it as close as possible to what you wanted. There are no rules as far as I know.

Comment: @Yiannis: It's a bad idea to use a negative space here. The space after `\sim` is strechable, so you won't get good results with `\!` or similar kerning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid this spacing you could define a symbol using `\sym` but as an ordinary math symbol instead of a relation symbol, such as

```
\newcommand*{\mysim}{\mathord{\sim}}
```

Comment: Spectacular!  I didn't know about mathord; that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As is explained in TeXbook, `\mathord` is not necessary. `{\sim}` is enough.

Comment: @Leo: That's right, though I use `\mathord` because it's clear what it's been done. We had this discussion [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/851/removing-spaces-between-words-in-math-mode/853#853).