# The use of "tilde" changes the proximity to the set theory symbol (ref img)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, tilde

I just want to format a simple set theory example. But the following is annoying:

[image]

See how close the cap gets to the 'A' because of the tilde sign? 
I've used sim for the tilde sign. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to tex.sx. A minimal document which generates this two lines would be very helpful, so that we can see which packages you are using and to test our answers.

Comment: $A$$=$$(A \cup B)$ \$A \cap (( A) \cap B)$ $= $ $ A \cap \sim B$ I use all the $$ to get extra space between the items.

Comment: better to edit your answer and place your sample code in there, rather than put it in a comment.  Indent it with four spaces to have it formatted like code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could avoid the binary operator spacing by writing `{\sim}` or `\mathord{\sim}`, achieving the same. You might have another look at [Spacing around a character in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9817/spacing-around-a-character-in-math-mode).

Comment: I love a quick fix. That did it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the following commands:

```
\, (\thinspace) 
\: (\medspace)
\; (\thickspace)
\quad 
\qquad
```

(They generate different spaces, but I don't know how to mark them in the code.) See also the [short math guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), p. 11.

---

EDIT: This solution should't be used here (see comments below). However, I'll not delete it as there is no harm to know about these commands.

Comment: You received a downvote because manual adjustments are not desirable in typesetting (although sometimes unavoidable); the whole point of using TeX is to forget about let the typesetting system worry about **consistently** positioning and spacing stuff around, allowing you to focus on the actual content. Compare this with the attitude of a Word/OO.o user, where manual adjustments and tweaks are the norm, rather the exception -- with unsurprisingly unimpressive results.

Comment: +1 from me, because these macros are more in the philosophy of math mode than stopping and starting math mode to insert spaces in LR mode.  But I agree with Martin that these adjustments are seldom necessary.

Comment: +1 from me too, specially in math mode. I just needed them.

Comment: Martin's quite right, _in this case_ it's not good to use those manual adjustments since there's a clean solution. But of course it's good to know the adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's doing that because `\sim` is meant as a binary operator (between two elements), rather than as a unary prefix operator (like set complement or negation).

You can always manually fix it up with extra space `\;` or negative space `\!` so for example, this looks approximately right:

```
A\; \cap \sim\!\!B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete code example with output (I just took Stefan's answer and wrote it out).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% TEX.SE \url{}
\setlength{\textwidth}{4in}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$A = (A \cup B)$

$A \cap (( A) \cap B) = A \cap \mathord{\sim}B$
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Switching in and out of math mode is not a good way to get extra spaces.  If you still want them after classifying the tilde as an ordinal, you can insert them with `\,`, `\;` , or `\` .  See [Herbert's mathmode document](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) for FMTYEWTK.