# Math spacing in captions

Tags: math-mode, spacing, captions

It seems that math in captions gets stretched out as illustrated in Figures 2, 3 and 4:

[image]

The problem shows up with `pdflatex` on the second run.

The solution given in [Lock spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129880/4301) of adding an additional curly brace `${y = mx + b}$` works but wondering if there is a better solution for captions.

A bit of stretch in order to justify text would be ok, but in this case that does not seem to be the issue and the stretching seems quite large.

### References:

- [Lock spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129880/4301)
- [Removing spaces between “words” in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/851/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}
  {format=plain,%
    font=footnotesize,
    textformat=period,
    justification=RaggedRight,
    singlelinecheck=true,
  }% all captions are left aligned

\DeclareCaptionStyle{singlelinecentered}
  [justification=Centering]% centered if single line and no `singlelinecheck=false`
  {style=mystyle}% other captions are left aligned

\DeclareCaptionStyle{singlelineraggedleft}
  [justification=RaggedLeft]% right aligned if single line and no `singlelinecheck=false`
  {style=mystyle}% other captions are left aligned

\captionsetup{style=singlelineraggedleft}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}%
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$ on Left}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$ on Right}%
\end{minipage}%

\medskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth,style=singlelinecentered}%
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your MWE (just like you posted it) using `pdflatex` I don't get any stretching. Both `xelatex` and `lualatex` result in the stretching you showed.

Comment: @Skillmon: Did you try running `pdflatex` twice. It seems to be ok on the first run, but not the second. BTW, .I am using pdflatex with TeXLive 2017.

Comment: That's the issue. Second run is stretched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see nothing strange and it hasn't to do with math, but rather with how `ragged2e` does its work.

1. In a `\RaggedRight`, `\RaggedLeft` or `\Centering` context, the `\spaceskip` parameter is set to `\spaceskip\fontdimen2\font`, that is, the normal interword space for the current font, but with no stretch and shrink.
2. In a `\RaggedRight` context, the values of `\rightskip` is set to `\RaggedRightRightskip` (default `0pt plus 2em`); similar settings are done for `\RaggedLeft` and `\Centering`.
3. A caption shorter than `\linewidth-2em` (for `\RaggedRight`) will need to be stretched.
4. The only stretchability is present in the spaces around binary operation and relation symbols.
5. Hey! Just math is stretched.

Solution: don't use `ragged2e` for this.

Alternative solution: remove the stretchability and shrinkability of `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\csappto{@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont}{%
  \medmuskip=1\medmuskip
  \thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip
}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}{
  format=plain,
  font=footnotesize,
  textformat=period,
  justification=RaggedRight,
  singlelinecheck=true,
  }% all captions are left aligned

\DeclareCaptionStyle{singlelinecentered}
  [justification=Centering]% centered if single line and no `singlelinecheck=false`
  {style=mystyle}% other captions are left aligned

\DeclareCaptionStyle{singlelineraggedleft}
  [justification=RaggedLeft]% right aligned if single line and no `singlelinecheck=false`
  {style=mystyle}% other captions are left aligned

\captionsetup{style=singlelineraggedleft}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$ on Left}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$ on Right}
\end{minipage}

\medskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth,style=singlelinecentered}%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}%
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{$y=mx+b$}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

But you'll get “Underfull `\hbox`” messages for every short caption.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Using `raggedright` instead of `RaggedRight` seems to work. Why is the spacing with `RaggedRight` ok after the first run?

Comment: @PeterGrill It's a `caption` feature: it wants to be sure that `ragged2e` is loaded, so it makes a note in the `.aux` file and, when it doesn't find it (first run), it uses `\raggedright` and similar from the kernel.