# Getting rid of unnecessary space between letters and equal sign in caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

Suppose we have this code

```
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
            \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
            \node[state] [right=of q_0] (q_1) {$q_1$};
            \path[->] 
            (q_0) edge node {$a,b$} (q_1)
            (q_1) edge [loop above] node {$a,b$} ();
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \captionof{figure}{This DFA represents $L_1 = \{\lambda\}$}
\end{center}
```

That produces: [image]

How do I get rid of the spacing between between the L_1 = and { }?

Is this because of the centering?

Comment: Apart from the linked answer I've mentioned in the comments to the answer provided, you could put the math in an `\mbox`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an answer but an extended comment that shows the importance of submitting a complete MWE. Without an MWE, one cannot reproduce your issue. If I compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
            \node[state,initial, accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
            \node[state] [right=of q_0] (q_1) {$q_1$};
            \path[->] 
            (q_0) edge node {$a,b$} (q_1)
            (q_1) edge [loop above] node {$a,b$} ();
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \captionof{figure}{This DFA represents $L_1 = \{\lambda\}$}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

That means that the weird behavior you are reporting does not come from the code *piece* that you are showing, but from something else. In many situations, when you try to write an MWE, you actually find the source of the problem yourself, and thus learn something. So

> PLEASE SUMBIT A COMPLETE MWE!

The above code qualifies as an MWE: it starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled. It is also rather minimal in the sense that (as far as I can tell) no unnecessary packages are loaded.

Comment: Hey marmot, I apologise for this. I found the mistake. My preamble is really long so I didn't think it was because of that but it was. This package "usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}" made the spaces. Thanks for the help and next time I will submit a complete MWE.

Comment: See the answer to [Math spacing in captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425712/22413)