# Remove the spaces between \times in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

My problem seems rather simple but I can't manage it. I want to describe bytes in this way

```
0000 xxxx
0010 1xxx
```

I tried by writing

```
0000 \times\times\times\times
0010 1\times\times\times
```

but this gave me too much spaces between the crosses (something like :

```
0000 x x x x
0010 1 x x x
```

I removed some spaces by doing like here ([Removing spaces between "words" in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/851/26803))

```
0000 {\times}{\times}{\times}{\times}
```

but this is not enough... Do you have any idea on how to do so?

I add here a MWE, as asked by some.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, scalerel}

\begin{document}
I want the bytes $0000\;1{\times}{\times}{\times}$ to express an error in my algorithm.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `\times` as a placeholder like that.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: What about using some mono spaced font: `\texttt{000 xxx}`?

Comment: @Sigur I'm satisfied with this solution for now... But the x is not really a cross, which does not really solve my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @mwoua, so change the font. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The symbol `\times` has rather wide sidebearings. I propose two solutions:

1. a reduced size symbol that occupies the same horizontal space as a digit;
2. the `\times` symbol at its natural width, with reduced sidebearings

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\plh}{%
  {\ooalign{$\phantom{0}$\cr\hidewidth$\scriptstyle\times$\cr}}%
}
\newcommand{\PLH}{{\mkern-2mu\times\mkern-2mu}}

\begin{document}
I want the bytes $0000\;1\plh\plh\plh$ to express an error in my algorithm.

I want the bytes $0000\;1\PLH\PLH\PLH$ to express an error in my algorithm.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I renewcommand `\times`?

Comment: @Hotschke You could, but why?

Comment: I have a densely packed table with math entries which I need to squeeze together. My first naive attempt using your answer by replacing `\newcommcand{\plh}` with `\renewcommand{\times}` did not work. However, I already resolved this with `\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}`. I was afraid that this would have too many side effects.

Comment: @Hotschke That setting *has* many side effects if you don't control precisely the environment where you issue it.

Comment: What does `plh` stand for?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq After six years, I have no idea why I chose that name. One can use any other name, though.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I want the bytes $0000\;1{\times}{\times}{\times}$ to express an error in my algorithm.

I want the bytes \texttt{0000 1xxx} to express an error in my algorithm.

I want the bytes \textsf{0000 1xxx} to express an error in my algorithm.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Event if I don't think it answers correctly my question, I will use your solutions. It looks better in my work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What do you think of using `mathsf`?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amssymb, scalerel}

    \newcommand*{\x}{\mathsf{x}\mskip1mu}

    \begin{document}

    I want the bytes $0000\;1\x\x\x$ to express an error in my algorithm.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's quite nice too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative spaces `\!`, or `\!\!` if one is not enough, which gives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, scalerel}

\begin{document}
I want the bytes $0000\;1\times\!\!\times\!\times$ to express an error in my algorithm.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with three `\times`?

Comment: Yes I do. It works too. You may refer to that question if you want to use more complex negative spacings: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67912/large-negative-spaces.

Comment: @egreg, good question!

Comment: Hum, sorry, this isn't working with 3 \times. But this does: $0000\;1\times\!\!\times\!\times$.

Comment: @Spin The spacing is inconsistent because `\times` is a binary operation symbol; you'd better use `{\times}` that forces it to ordinary. But in that case `\!` is too much.

Comment: Yep, I figured this out... It's not a very good idea to use this symbol in that kind of situation.